# JOptionPane Array conditions

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

How can I display ZERO, POSITIVE, NEGATIVE string with corresponding array in one JOptionPane message?

Here is the code....

```
    String display="";
    int z = 0;

    String size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Prefered Size Of Your Array");
    int newsize = Integer.parseInt(size);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Entered "+newsize+".");

    int array[] = new int [newsize];

    for (int a=0; a<array.length;a++)
    {
        array[a] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"]."));

    }



    for (int a=0;a<array.length;a++)
    {
        display=display+array[a]+"\n";

        if (z == array[a])
        {
          String c=array[a]+"  ZERO";
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
        }
        else if (z < array[a])
        {
            String c =array[a]+"  POSITIVE";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
        }
        else if (z != array[a])
        {
            String c =array[a]+"  NEGATIVE";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display+c);
     }
```

Comment: anmf, i prefer to compile the code by your self, if you dont mind, then for sure you will get my question.:))

Comment: I have edited your question to try to make it more clear, but I don't really get it. You should be more explicit on what you want and what you obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after:

```
public class SO2{
public static void main(String[] args) {

 String display="";
 int z = 0;

    String size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Prefered Size Of Your Array");
    int newsize = Integer.parseInt(size);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Entered "+newsize+".");
    int array[] = new int [newsize]; //Sets array

    for (int a=0; a<array.length;a++){//Puts values in array
        array[a] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"]."));
    }   

    for (int a=0;a<array.length;a++){
        display=display+array[a]+"\n";
    }

    String toShow = ""; //String to build up
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == 0){
            display = "ZERO";
        } else if(array[i] < 0){
            display = "NEGATIVE";
        } else if(array[i] > 0){
            display = "POSITIVE";
        }

        toShow += "Array element " + i + " is " + array[i] + " and it is " + display + "\n"; //Build string
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers...\n\n"+toShow);//show
}}
```

It shows all the numbers from the array with their POS/NEG/ZERO values next to them. I have added some comments to try and explain a little

Good luck!